# In a JS Request, what happens if u specify both Request.cache and Cache Control header?

Tags: javascript, caching, request

I'm talking about these two:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/cache
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control

I can't find much info on which of the 2 have higher priority.

In my case I want to filter some requests and change them to no-cache, and I'm doing it by editing the Cache Control header. But I found out about the cache field too and I'm not sure if I should also edit it, which is a bit more complex since it can only store one value.

So if the request.cache is "no-store" but the request Cache Control is "no-cache", will the response then be cached or not stored?

To be sure, I'm talking about Requests and not Responses in this case.

Thanks!